# cURL cannot connect to host

Tags: php, curl

I am getting the issue in curl function. When I run the url direct in browser then it shows the content but when I use that url in curl function then it is showing the following message.

```
  Array
  7
 couldn't connect to host
 bool(false)
```

I am using the following code:

```
   $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$queryurl);
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json',
'Host: http://cloud.softpanda.com.au'
     ));
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL you specified returns a 301 redirect to http://www.softpanda.com.au, so you will likely not get the content unless you either correct the URL or set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to TRUE, which will follow redirects such as what you're getting.

Comment: Which variable are you using for the URL?  I'm seeing 2 changes: one with $url and the other with $queryurl.

Comment: I am using the $url, both are same

Comment: I also noticed the URL you're trying to reach is also HTTPS.  I get data back when I test it using `https://cloud.softpanda.com.au`. Note you will get a 400 Bad Request if you set your header for json on that URL, though.  Remove the header and it works.  (Can't get the hang of this markdown for comments yet, sorry)

Comment: Here's what I have, and it returns data for me:
`$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://cloud.softpanda.com.au");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;
`

Comment: Now it is showing  'bool(false) ' but when I run url directy in browser then it shows the content

Comment: You only have the CURL connection code posted.  Edit your original post to include your entire script or post as another issue perhaps since the error is somewhere else in your code now.

Comment: I am using the curl code only , i am sending the some creditional in url that I am using in curl .  but it is also showing the error 'couldn't connect to host'. Should I need to check that in cpanel?